# Is there a way to improve Xcode's code completion?

Tags: xcode, code-completion

For some reason, not sure exactly since when (it wasn't always like this) but, when I want to write down **NSDictionary**, up to **NSDi** it is suggesting me **NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants**.

At what point designing the algorithm, which surely makes use of some NSDictionaries along the way, did the engineers at Apple think "Wow, this is really useful! I use **NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants** so often!"?

Is there some way to bring back some sanity to it?

Comment: Just be thankful there's code completion at all.

Comment: When code completion seems to be misbehaving, it is usually because you've got an error higher up in your code. Find and fix it.

Comment: @MiloGosnell if everyone though like that we wouldn't even have computers by now. "We already have pencil and papel to do computation! Be thankful".

Comment: @matt I do experience that pretty often, but this isn't the case. It's like code completion isn't tracking my most used methods and classes, which I'm sure it was before.

Comment: No, I don't believe code completion has ever had any "intelligence" about this. It does tend to start by selecting the one you most recently selected, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give the [Xcode Fuzzy Autocomplete](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin) plugin a whirl.

I recommend first installing [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/), an Xcode package manager, which will allow you to easily enable and disable this plugin, not to mention discover other interesting ones.

Comment: You got your accepted answer! This plugin is the answer to all my prayers :)